# What happends when we multiply an integral by itself?

Tags: integration

What happens when we multiply an integral by itself?
$$
  \left(\int_{z}^{q} y(x)\;\mathrm{d}x\right)^2 = 
  \left(\int_{z}^{q} y(x)\;\mathrm{d}x\right)
  \left(\int_{z}^{q} y(x)\;\mathrm{d}x\right) =\quad?
$$

Comment: It gets squared

Comment: What is the closed form of the new integral

Comment: It is less than the integral of the integrand, squared. See Hölder's inequality.

Comment: Just change the variable of integration in the second from $x$ to any other unused letter, like, say, $z$, then it becomes a double integral over that square of $y(x)y(z)dxdz$

Comment: @RaceBannon are you sure? Let $f = 0.5$, $a = 0$, $b = 2$. Then
$$\left(\int_a^b f \, \mathrm{d}x\right)^2 = 1$$ but $$\int_a^b f^2 \, \mathrm{d}x = 0.5.$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the integrand is absolutely convergent, then you may use [Fubini's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fubini%27s_theorem) and obtain
$$
\left(\int_{z}^{q} y(x)dx\right)^2=\int_{z} ^{q}\! \int_{z} ^{q} y(x)y(t)\:dxdt
$$ as Alan pointed out in the comments.